# Computing permutation character associated to a Young subgroup.

Tags: symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

If $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ is a partition of $n$, then there is a permutation character of $S_n$ associated to the Young subgroup $S_\lambda$:
$$
\pi_\lambda = \mathrm{Ind}_{S_\lambda}^{S_n}(1).
$$
For a permutation $\sigma$, you can check that the formula for the value of $\pi_\lambda$ is given by
$$
\pi_{\lambda} (\tau) = \frac{|\{ \sigma\in S_n : \sigma^{-1}\tau \sigma \in S_\lambda \}|}{|S_\lambda|}.
$$

Is there an easy way to compute the number $|\{\sigma\in S_n : \sigma^{-1}\tau \sigma \in S_\lambda\}|$ given the cycle type of $\tau$?

Comment: Is your formula correct? Since conjugation by $\sigma$ is a bijection, isn't the cardinality you write down simply $|S_\lambda|$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven There was indeed a typo, which is fixed now.

Comment: So I guess you mean $\pi_\lambda(\tau)$ now?

Comment: Yes, hopefully that is the last typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_l)$ is a partition of $n$ and $\tau\in S_n$ is a permutation of cycle type $\mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_r)$, then the value of the permutation character $\pi_\lambda(\tau)$ is given by the coefficient of $x_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots x_l^{\lambda_l}$ in the product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^r (x_1^{\mu_i} + \cdots + x_l^{\mu_i}).
$$

If you know of other ways to compute the value, please do still post your method.